# UART baudrate on ATmega328P

Tags: avr, c

I've written a program to run the UART on a custom board using the the ATmega328P only with the internal oscillator.

Here is my code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define BAUD 9600 
#define MYUBRR    F_CPU/16/BAUD-1

void init_uart(unsigned short uValue  ){
    // setting the baud rate 
    UBRR0H =(unsigned char)  ( uValue>> 8);  // 0x00 
    UBRR0L =(unsigned char) uValue;  // 0x0C
    // enabling TX & RX 
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0A = (1<<UDRE0);
    UCSR0C =  (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);    // Set frame: 8data, 1 stop
    
}
int main (){
    init_uart(MYUBRR);
    DDRD |= (1<< PD7);
    for(;;){
        PORTD ^= (1<< PD7);
        UDR0 = 'k';
        //_delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've set the register values based on the example in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) page 241.
The problem that I have is that I'm not receiving the word correctly.

Here's what I get:

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: How is your custom board connected to the PC?

Comment: I'm using the FTDI breakboard

Comment: Your code is close to these tutorials but I would try one and see if it works. Then you can customize it, if needed, to make it your own. https://hekilledmywire.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-the-usartserial-tutorial-part-2/
https://bennthomsen.wordpress.com/arduino/peripherals/serial-communications/

Comment: I've been there , the guy is using 16Mhz crystal I've change it 1Mhz but still  have the same problem

Comment: If it's not your AVR code then double check your FTDI connections and configuration, and your Putty COM port settings.

Comment: already done, I've tried also with arduino IDE it didn't help! thanks a lot for your input

Comment: You're welcome... Just keep at it. UART/com problems like these usually end up being something small or simple that you're just overlooking/missing.

Comment: You might consider using <util/setbaud.h>. It takes F_CPU and will generate UBRR values for you (along with the 2X flag).

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I had to wait on the transmitter and receive flags.

This is the working code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define BAUD 9600 
#define MYUBRR    F_CPU/8/BAUD-1

void init_uart(unsigned short uValue  ){
    // setting the baud rate  based on the datasheet 
    UBRR0H =0x00;//(unsigned char)  ( uValue>> 8);  // 0x00 
    UBRR0L =0x0C;//(unsigned char) uValue;  // 0x0C  
    // enabling TX & RX 
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0A = (1<<UDRE0)|(1<<U2X0);
    UCSR0C =  (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);    // Set frame: 8data, 1 stop
    
}
  
unsigned char USART_Receive( void )
{
    /* Wait for data to be received */
    while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) )
    ;
    /* Get and return received data from buffer */
    return UDR0;
}
void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data )
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) )
    ;
    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

int main (){
    init_uart(MYUBRR);
    DDRD |= (1<< PD7);
    for(;;){
        PORTD ^= (1<< PD7);
        USART_Transmit('x');
        USART_Transmit('l');
        //_delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```